# VueJS - How to get a single file component's instance in the script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I have a single file component `dashboard.vue`. In its script tag, I have the following code.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function(){
            return {
                scrolled: false,
            }
        },
    };
    $window.on({
        scroll: function(){
            this.scrolled = true;
        },
    });
</script>
```

How can I access the component's vue instance in the `$window.on` event listener to update the data? I know why `this` won't work in the current setup, just need to know what will. Cheers.

Comment: Inside of your default exported object, add a `created` method and put the code there (you'll have access to `this`) cf. [Vue lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move your event listener inside the `created` or `mounted` hook ..

```
  <script>
    export default {
      data: function () {
        return {
          scrolled: false,
        }
      },
      created() {
        const self = this
        $(window).on({
          scroll: function () {
            self.scrolled = true
          }
        })
      },
      beforeDestroy() {
        $(window).off("scroll")
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Don't forget to remove it in the `beforeDestroy` hook.

Comment: Cheers. Just wondering if you could give me an example of when forgetting to remove the listener in the `beforeDestroy` hook cause problems.

Comment: @Mav As a rule of thumb, you should think about manual cleanup whenever you use an external libraray with Vue. This is mainly because it [might lead to memory leaks](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html#Introduction). In your case it might introduce a bug because your event listener's callback is referencing the component's instance, causing problems if the listener is active after the component is destroyed.